# Al presionar botón de registro detiene aplicación

Tags: java, android-studio, botón, aplicación-movil

pero a la ahora de presionar el botón de registro dice que la aplicación se a detenido he buscado el error y no lo consigo por ningún lado me podrían decir que sucede

código de active_ main

```
 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
     
        android:layout_marginBottom="479dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login_btn"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      
        android:text="iniciar sesion " />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/register_btn"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       
        android:text="Registrar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

este es el codigo de mainactivity.java

cuando le doy click en el botón  de registro dice que se ha detenido y se cierra solo

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button mRegisterBtn, mLoginBtn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRegisterBtn = findViewById(R.id.register_btn);
        mLoginBtn = findViewById(R.id.login_btn);

mRegisterBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
//comienzo de registro
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterActivity2.class));

    }
});

    }
}
```

Comment: Agrega el mensaje de error por favor.

Comment: hola cuando estoy en la prueba de la aplicación,  dice que la aplicación se ha detenido y no me muestra ningún error de código

Comment: Es importante el uso del LogCat, ahí se muestra el error que comenta @DavElsanto si no usas el LogCat puedes tardar días en solucionar un problema en lugar de unos  segundos, revisa: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat?hl=es